# Rails NoMethodError: undefined method `includes' for #<User:0x007f62dbbe62f8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

I'm using the `active_model_serializers` gem in my Rails 5 app. I created a few serializer files in `/app/seralizers`, `user_serializer.rb`, `sector_serializer.rb`, and `slot_serializer.rb` .

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :admin, :auth_token, :organization_id

    has_many :sectors
    has_many :slots
    has_many :elements
end

class SectorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :user_id, :sector_number, :title

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :slots
    has_many :elements
end

class SlotSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :user_id, :sector_id, :sector_number, :title, :slot_number

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :sector
    has_many :elements
end
```

And in my controller code, I have:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < API::V1::BaseController
  respond_to :json

  def sky
      @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]).includes(:sectors, :slots)

      if @user
        render json: @user
      else
          raise "Unable to get Sky"
      end
  end
end
```

My server is throwing an error at the line where I do the `.includes` and I can't figure out why.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Change

```
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]).includes(:sectors, :slots)
```

to

```
@user = User.includes(:sectors, :slots).find_by_id(params[:user_id])
```

Point is you have to call `includes` on a class (that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`/`ApplicationRecord`), not a single user object.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much Ursus

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)